# segmentation fault during pthread_exit()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I've a problem finishing a thread, and doing the debug with GDB I've found that I've a segmentation after invoking the function pthread_exit(NULL);

Some messages which I've are

1. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   [Switching to LWP 12371]
   0x400e9fd0 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6

Debugging with this option "gdb -c core EMBEDDED" I've got this warning message

"warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Core was generated by `/home/root/SSL/EMBEDDED'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

## 0  0x400e9fd0 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6"

Some advices, some suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the code?

Comment: Hi, the code is single, it's created inside other thread like this...

pthread_create( &rx_gprs, NULL, &f_rx_gprs , NULL);

and the code has the next structure

void * f_rx_gprs(){
  //variable declaration
  while(!STOP_THREAD){
    downloadfile();

  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

And making the debug the error is when the thread invoke pthread_exit.

Thanks for your answer @ManojPandey

Comment: I've changed the pthread_exit(NULL) in this thread per return NULL and now I don't have the segmentation fault, Someone has a reason??

Comment: The problem was solved. First, I've replaced the pthread_exit(NULL) by only NULL at the end of the thread, it works for just a hours, but checking again and again my code, I've found that I was pointing a function wrong and because of it, I was touching some value in the stack of the thread.

Other thing, If someone know what happen with the youtube channel the shell wave, please let me know, I was a great course for linux and that disappeared. Thanks